# ant command does not generating apk file

Tags: android, ant, build, apk

I am using Ant to build my application.my app uses a library project.so first of all i had run the below command in commandline to generate the build.xml in my project.

"**android update
 project --target 5 -p path_of_my_project -l path_of_my_library_project**"

(my application's build target is 4.0).Above command generated a build.xml file in my project.Then i run "ant" command in command prompt.it has shown the result as BUILD SUCCESSFULL. but when i checked my project's bin folder there is no apk file is generated.what is the issue?I did not make any changes in build.xml file.do i need to add something to that to generate the build?please guide me.

Comment: Are you sure without compiling the code you will get the apk.

Comment: check the path where you are saving the apk file from your ant script.

Comment: actually i am new to Ant.so i dont know what all are the steps to build the apk.:(

Comment: do we need compile in ant script to run the "ant compile" command in command line?when i am running the command "ant compile" it is returning error message as "target compile does not exists in the project"