# how to generate apk using ant

Tags: android, ant, apk

i want to know how can we generate apk file using ant script. i came to know that we can use "ant debug" command to do that.but when i am running this command it is returning error that " Target "debug" does not exist in the project". i am using ant1.7.0.is it the issue?i have tried given below code to generate apk.

```
 <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build">
    <jar destfile="bin/test.apk" basedir="bin/classes" >
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.Main" />
  </manifest>
</jar>
    </target>
```

but the generated apk is different from auto generated apk while build the app using eclipse.Please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ant command does not generating apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951644/ant-command-does-not-generating-apk-file)

Comment: I don't understand. If you say it gives 'target doesn't exist' error, then why is it building an apk at all?

Comment: Using Ant to Automate Building Android Applications: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html

Comment: in apk file which i have generated though ant,only main class details is der in the manifest file.but in the other one there no value like main class and resource values are there

Comment: In system requirements it does specify that Ant version 1.8 is necessary. It does not specify what the consequences of using a lower version are. It would do no harm to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

> but when i am running this command it is returning error that " Target "debug" does not exist in the project"

Then you did not create your Android project properly, or you modified your `build.xml` file, or something else is broken.

As a test, I just ran the following command from my `/tmp` directory on Linux:

```
android create project --target android-17 --path Foo --package com.foo --activity Foo
```

I then changed into the `Foo` directory and ran `ant debug`. The app compiled, and in my `bin/` directory is `Foo-debug.apk`.

If you are not getting this sort of result, delete your `build.xml` file and run `android update project --path ...`, where `...` is the path to your project, to create a fresh `build.xml` file.

Comment: first i run ant debug command.Then it has shown the error "build.xml does not exists".after that i have exported build.xml using eclipse ant.then again run the command "ant debug" now it is showing the error "Target "debug" does not exist in the project"

Comment: @seethalakshmi: "after that i have exported build.xml using eclipse ant" -- you will notice that I never told you to do that. Please read the documentation about `android update project`: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject Then please follow the instructions.