# Re-initialize and build Android project from the command line?

Tags: android, linux, command-line

I have previously only once built an Android project successfully on my Linux machine; for that, I downloaded the Android SDK and ultimately used `gradlew` to build it, which worked fine.

Now, I got a zip containing an Android project source code; however, as I'm not experienced with this, I have no idea what this project was made in, nor how was it built. The directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── assets
├── bin
│   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── com # ... .class files here
...
│   ├── jarlist.cache
│   └── res
├── gen
│   └── com     # ... BuildConfig.java here
...
│   └── android-support-v4.jar
├── lint.xml
├── proguard-project.txt
├── project.properties
├── res
│   ├── drawable       # ... .png files here
...
│   ├── drawable-hdpi  # many similar dirs, launcher.png file
...
│   ├── layout         # main.xml and other .xml files
...
│   ├── raw            # some .json files here
...
│   ├── values         # also values-v11, values-v14 dirs; has styles.xml
...
└── src
    └── com            # .java source files here
...
```

I have tried [How/when to generate Gradle wrapper files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files) in this directory (that is, `gradlew wrapper` and `gradlew init`), but even if gradle-specific files are generated, I cannot build that - since I cannot run `gradlew assemble` or `gradlew build`, as I get "`Task 'assemble' not found in root project`".

After finding [Build Android project on command line on OSX: Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490616/build-android-project-on-command-line-on-osx-task-assembledebug-not-found-in), I thought maybe it has to be compiled with `ant`, but that fails with "`Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!`" (and indeed, such a file doesn't exist).

From what I read around, I guess one should download Android Studio and try opening the project there -- but I'd rather not download/learn/use yet another IDE (I use a standalone text editor and I don't use, say, Eclipse), and would rather get this done through the command line.

So how could I "re-initialize" this project, so I can build it with command line tools on Linux (`gradle` or `ant`, though I guess `gradle` is preferred, as apparently `ant` is [not currently supported by Android team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490616/build-android-project-on-command-line-on-osx-task-assembledebug-not-found-in))?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that there was actually a hidden file in this project, `.project`, which has for instance:

```
<buildCommand>
  <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
  <arguments>
  </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

... which means this had been built with Eclipse with ADT plugin ( http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html ), the support for which is now discontinued in favor of Android Studio ( [Migrating to Android Studio | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) ).

Knowing this, then I simply found [How to create build.xml for an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718907/how-to-create-build-xml-for-an-android-project) and [ant command does not generating apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951644/ant-command-does-not-generating-apk-file), from where I tried the command:

```
/path/to/sdk/tools/android update project -p $PWD
```

... which finally did create `build.xml` that is used by the `ant` system - which seemed to pass (but the build itself failed due to unresolved library dependencies, which is a different topic).

There seems to be no easy way to convert an `ant` based project to a `gradle` one from the command line - and even the migration path through the Android Studio may/will require manual changes.